# Variable number of SharedMemory objects managed by SharedMemoryManager in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, producer-consumer

I would like to have a variable number of [`SharedMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) objects (depending on the number of consumer processes in my producer-consumer app architecture) managed by [`SharedMemoryManager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.managers.SharedMemoryManager) so I am creating
`SharedMemory` objects in the manager's "scope" in a for loop. Unfortunately, only the shared memory that is created last can be accessed by its name, the previous ones are probably somehow destroyed.

This code produces the described behavior. I am using Python 3.10.

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

consumer_process_count = 3

with SharedMemoryManager() as memory_manager:
    memory_names = []
    for i in range(consumer_process_count):
        shared_memory = memory_manager.SharedMemory(size=1)
        memory_names.append(shared_memory.name)
        print(f"Memory {shared_memory.name} created.")

    for memory_name in memory_names:
        try:
            SharedMemory(name=memory_name)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Memory {memory_name} not found.")
        else:
            print(f"Memory {memory_name} found.")
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to use `SharedMemoryManager` to manage variable number of `SharedMemory` objects?

I have a workaround solution that doesn't use `SharedMemoryManager` but I wanted to make my code cleaner and also use the advantage of having the context manager take care of resource cleanup whenever there is an unexpected error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that as you proceed through the loop executing `shared_memory = memory_manager.SharedMemory(size=1)`, you are overlaying the previous value of `shared_memory` with the new one and since there are no longer any references to that prior shared memory instance, it is being "closed" rendering it inaccessible. I would suspect that you are able to find the last shared memory block that was allocated by name since a reference to it still exists.

The solution is to keep a reference to all shared memory blocks allocated. For example, append the shared memory block reference to a list, `shared_memories` thus preventing the block from being rendered inaccessible:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
    from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

    consumer_process_count = 3

    with SharedMemoryManager() as memory_manager:
        shared_memories = []
        memory_names = []
        for i in range(consumer_process_count):
            shared_memory = memory_manager.SharedMemory(size=1)
            shared_memories.append(shared_memory)
            memory_names.append(shared_memory.name)
            print(f"Memory {shared_memory.name} created.")

        for memory_name in memory_names:
            try:
                SharedMemory(name=memory_name)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print(f"Memory {memory_name} not found.")
            else:
                print(f"Memory {memory_name} found.")
```

Prints:

```None
Memory wnsm_5e0842b0 created.
Memory wnsm_1a9758ac created.
Memory wnsm_e93c9e19 created.
Memory wnsm_5e0842b0 found.
Memory wnsm_1a9758ac found.
Memory wnsm_e93c9e19 found
```

**Explanation**

Looking at the library code it appears that when the shared memory manger creates a shared memory block it keeps only the name of the shared memory and not the actual reference to the `multiprocessing.shared_memory` instance that is returned to the caller. When there are no more references to the actual memory, which occurs in your original code, method `__del__` is called on the instance, which issues a call to `close()` on the shared memory block. So strictly speaking, the shared memory block has not been "unlinked" by this action, but according to the documentation for `close()` :

> Closes access to the shared memory from this instance. In order to ensure proper cleanup of resources, all instances should call close() once the instance is no longer needed. Note that calling close() does not cause the shared memory block itself to be destroyed.

So the block may still exist but it can no longer be accessed.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the problem. I understand that once there is no reference to an object, it is garbage collected, at least that is Python's general behavior. But once there is some context manager involved, I would expect that objects can be garbage collected during the `__exit__()` method and not sooner. Moreover if the objects are accessed by name from a different process and not passed by reference (therefore, no reference has to be kept). If there is some key concept that I'm missing, please explain. Otherwise, I find this behavior kind of fluky and I hope it improves in the future.

Comment: I have added an explanation to the answer.